# PCL Header timestamp

Tags: pcl, roscpp, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The pcl_ros tutorial example doesn't work:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> PointCloud;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init (argc, argv, "pub_pcl");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<PointCloud> ("points2", 1);

    PointCloud::Ptr msg (new PointCloud);
    msg->header.frame_id = "some_tf_frame";
    msg->height = msg->width = 1;
    msg->points.push_back (pcl::PointXYZ(1.0, 2.0, 3.0));

    ros::Rate loop_rate(4);
    while (nh.ok())
    {
        msg->header.stamp = ros::Time::now ();
        pub.publish (msg);
        ros::spinOnce ();
        loop_rate.sleep ();
   } 
}
```

The compiler complains with the following:

```
error: no se puede convertir ‘ros::Time’ a ‘uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}’ en la asignación (it's in Spanish, I don't know how to change my compiler language)
```

which is something like:

```
error: 'ros::Time' cannot be converted to 'uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}' in assignment
```

Has somebody else faced this problem? I am running ROS Hydro, on Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172730/pcl-header-timestamp/) by [crpizarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9346/crpizarr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2014-06-03

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is related to changes of the Timestamp type in PCL. See the [hydro migration guide](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration#PCL) for instructions on how to solve this problem. You´ll probably find some more examples of this issue on ROS Answers, too (for example also [this Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/83341/pcl-package-on-ros-hydro-compiling-errors/) or [this Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/105871/rgbd-in-hydro/)).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`pcl_conversions` has conversion functions : http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/pcl_conversions/html/pcl__conversions_8h_source.html

To convert the time:

```
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
...
pcl_conversions::toPCL(ros::Time::now(), point_cloud_msg->header.stamp);
```

Or convert an entire header from a ros message:

```
pcl_conversions::toPCL(ros_msg->header, point_cloud_msg>header);
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2015-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luator](https://answers.ros.org/users/21035/luator/) on 2015-03-20**:
Thanks for noting this here, as the documentation for pcl_conversion seems to be non-existing (at least in the [ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_conversions))...

**Comment by [stevenwaslander](https://answers.ros.org/users/20407/stevenwaslander/) on 2015-07-03**:
I ran into this issue too, and a previous fix using point_cloud_msg->header.stamp = ros::Time::now().toNSec() stopped working recently.  Hopefully this conversion will stay up to date between the two code bases.